# What would cause a 500 Server Error with permalinks turned OFF?

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, 500-internal-error

I'm using the "default" setting for permalinks, at least I just switched back to that, and I'm still getting a 500 response code when trying to get to any post page like mysite.com/?p=4536

I can see how that could happen with permalinks on, with the .htaccess file causing some strange things, but why would it possibly ever happen with a blank .htaccess file, and no permalinks on? Any thoughts?

#### Update 1

- I checked the error logs, nothing helpful there except a mention of the errors.
- I purposefully cleared the .htaccess in order to see if it was a problem, and the server error is still occurring.
- The front page of the site is up and running fine, but when you click to a post, with permalinks turned on or without, it returns the 500 error.

Comment: I think problem in cache plugin or memory limit (php.ini)

Comment: I deactivated all plugins one by one and there is no change. I'm not sure why memory limit would make a post have a 500 error when the home page works fine?

Comment: Try add to wp-config.php this line `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');` or more..

Comment: I don't think it's helpful to suggest doing that without any reason why it would fix this problem. I wouldn't want my clients to start arbitrarily increasing their memory limits because of a 500 server error. Especially when the error is specific to a certain set of pages and not across the entire site.

Answer (score 1):

- Error 500 ISE is very generic and can be caused by numerous underlying issues. Your first step should be locating error log for your hosting account or asking support to help with that.
- It may indicate .htaccess issue. Regenerate .htaccess, and be sure the encoding in your text editor is Unicode No BOM
- It may also indicate a problem with the configuration on the server. Usually your hosting company tech support can help.

Comment: Thanks, so I think we can rule out all these things, at least under the conditions I listed in "Update 1" above. Let me know if that makes anything clearer.